# JSP tags: manipulating body content *before* it is evaluated

Tags: jsp

I couldn't figure how I can manipulate the body content before its first evaluation. Someone knows how to?

[I did succeed manipulating it after the first evaluation, using the BodyTagSupport class by overriding the doAfterBody() method].

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [BodyTag](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/BodyTag.html).doInitBody()

> Prepare for evaluation of the body.
>   This method is invoked by the JSP page
>   implementation object after
>   setBodyContent and before the first
>   time the body is to be evaluated. This
>   method will not be invoked for empty
>   tags or for non-empty tags whose
>   doStartTag() method returns SKIP_BODY
>   or EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unsure of what you want to do since the jsp tag is basically compiled into code. But the tag (and its body) produces an output which is known as a jsp fragment, and this can be manipulated.

Pardon for using the simple tag syntax but you can basically use the

<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

This defines a variable that you can manipulate with other functions. You can later emit the contents of this variable to the output stream.